# Compare current system date with another date(which is coming as string format 2019-11-22) in swift

Tags: swift

I'm getting date as a sting format from API (2019-11-22),  I want to compare this date with current date.

I tried converting current date as string format this is success but this is not satisfying requiremet. I have to convert to  String(2019-11-22) to Date and then I can compare two dates.

How can I convert string (2019-11-22) to Date to compare with system date pls help I'm lead knowledge in dates. Thanks in advance.

```
extension Date {
static func getCurrentDate() -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
}
```

}

```
        if Date() < apiEach["ExpiryDate"]! as! Date{
        //apiEach["ExpiryDate"]! is 2019-11-22
        pritn("You can proceed it's not outdated")
    }
```

Comment: Use the date formatter you have to convert your string to a Date object then you can directly compare it to `Date()`

Comment: Pls help me on that converting string to date, I'm new to swift.

Comment: Use the date formatter you have, `let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2019-11-22")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apiEach["ExpiryDate"]` is a string (`apiEach["ExpiryDate"] as! Date` will crash) so you have two options:

1. Convert the current date to string

   ```
   if Date.getCurrentDate() < apiEach["ExpiryDate"] as! String { ...
   ```
2. Convert the API string to `Date` and compare that

   ```
   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
   dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
   if let apiDate = dateFormatter.date(from: apiEach["ExpiryDate"] as! String),
      Date() < apiDate { ...
   ```

Comment: HI Vadian, Your answer 2 is working fine. Can you pls help me comparing only with date without time?? This answer is comparing with time and **Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")** is taking US hours due to that I'm facing issue in other countries. @vadian

Comment: @Rahul `yyyy-MM-dd` is a fixed date format regardless of the current locale and the code does compare without time.

Answer (score 0):

```
func minimumDate(result:String) -> Bool {
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let myDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "\(result)")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"


let now = Date()
let startDateComparisionResult:ComparisonResult = now.compare(myDate!)
if startDateComparisionResult == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending {
    print("Current date is smaller than end date.")
    let somedateString = dateFormatter.string(from: myDate!)
    print(somedateString)
    return true
}
else if startDateComparisionResult == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending {
    // Current date is greater than end date.
    print("Current date is greater than end date.")
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let date1String = dateFormatter.string(from: myDate!)
    let date2String = dateFormatter.string(from: now)
    if date1String == date2String {
        print("Equal date")
        return true
    }
    return false
}
else if startDateComparisionResult == ComparisonResult.orderedSame {
    // Current date and end date are same
    print("Current date and end date are same")

    return true

}

return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the date format "yyyy-MM-dd" can be properly sorted/compared you can either convert current date to a string and compare it with your API value

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let now = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())

switch now.compare(input) { //input is from API
    case .orderedSame:
       print("Same")
    case .orderedAscending:
       print("Before")
    case .orderedDescending:
       print("After")
}
```

If you want to compare dates it is important that `Date()` will also include the current time while a date converted using a date formatter with a date only format will have its time zeroed out (midnight) so the comparison might not be correct if the date part is the same. To handle this it is better to use DateComponents

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: input) else { return //or error }
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: now, to: date)

if let year = components.year, let month = components.month, let day = components.day {
    switch (year + month + day) {
        case 0:  // all values are zero
            print("Same")
        case ..<0 : // values will be zero or negative so sum is negative
            print("After")
        default:  // values will be zero or positive so sum is positive
            print("Before")
    }
}
```